# Best method to disable sharepoint CHOICE field using JQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I've a simple requirement to disable a number of choice fields in a SharePoint Edit form.

I tried setting the attr('readonly','readonly') that didn't work, the choice field was still editable.

I then tried attr('disabled','disabled') this worked, in that the field was greyed out, with the previously set value displayed.. But on saving the other edited values the choice field reverted to hte first item in the choice list...

Any ideas gratefully received, I'm pretty new to this!

Cheers

Russ

```
   $("document").ready(function() {
    //$("select[title='Department']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    //$("select[title='Department']").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you only apply that when your select is set to Department. If is that you need to create another function to removeAttr('disabled').

Once it is applied the attribute isn't removed automatically. Your code are saying that when document is ready (request) disable all select fields with Department.

Comment: Hi There, thansk for the response, could you ponit me at an example of how to remove the attribute prior to submitting the form please?!

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, what would the JQuery code look like, setting the disabled then unsetting before submit. I'm unsure how to do this?!

Answer (score 0):

In your XSL, replace your SharePoint:SaveButton control by using SharePoint Designer and adding a Form Action Button instead.

This...
<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton1" />

Changes to this...
<input type="button" id="savebutton1" name="savebutton1" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" value="Save" onclick="javascript: $('select[title=&quot;Department&quot;]').removeAttr('disabled'); {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')}" />

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint list forms actually expose a way of attaching functionality to the save action in the form of a JavaScript function called `PreSaveAction`

Declare this on your listform and it will be called after a user clicks Ok and before the form  posts back. Re-enable the field here. You must return a boolean that lets the form know whether it should continue with the save.

E.g.

```
function PreSaveAction() {
   alert("Hi");
   // Re-enable any disabled fields here
   return true;
}
```